# how to change the position of the axis label on a fusionchart?

Tags: fusioncharts

Here i am trying to change the position of the axis labels for the fusioncharts. I am using fusioncharts to generate the reports.The problem is the labels for the axes(both x and y) are not at the position i want to them.I want to change the position of those labels.Is there any way to do this without affecting the fusioncharts in any way?
This is what i want to achieve:

```
![Required Image][1]
![Original Image][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CviVz.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpXOq.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionCharts does not provide axis name alignment configurations. This is primarily because non-center alignment of axis names can cause ambiguity while perceiving the chart.